# How to add more OR searches with CONTAINS Brings Query to Crawl?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I have a simple query that relies on two full-text indexed tables, but it runs extremely slow when I have the **CONTAINS** combined with any additional **OR** search. As seen in the execution plan, the two full text searches crush the performance. If I query with just 1 of the CONTAINS, or neither, the query is sub-second, but the moment you add **OR** into the mix the query becomes ill-fated.

The two tables are nothing special, they're not overly wide (42 cols in one, 21 in the other; maybe 10 cols are FT indexed in each) or even contain very many records (36k recs in the biggest of the two).

I was able to solve the performance by splitting the two **CONTAINS** searches into their own **SELECT** queries and then **UNION** the three together. Is this UNION workaround my only hope?

```
SELECT     a.CollectionID
FROM       collections    a
INNER JOIN determinations b ON a.CollectionID = b.CollectionID 
WHERE      a.CollrTeam_Text LIKE '%fa%'
           OR CONTAINS(a.*, '"*fa*"')
           OR CONTAINS(b.*, '"*fa*"')
```

Execution Plan:

[image: execution plan]

Comment: I should point out @ChiragRoy says it is a known issue with SQL2008/R2 with an open PSS case. But I am curious if anyone else has ran into the problem and found an alternative solution or reason for the issue.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the protocol is for marking a single answer as answered.  In this case, UNION definitely solves the issue, but it would appear I can solve the problem AND get better performance with CONTAINSTABLE.  I really appreciate everyone's feedback on the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd be curious to see if a LEFT JOIN to an equivalent CONTAINSTABLE would perform any better. Something like:

```
SELECT     a.CollectionID
FROM       collections    a
INNER JOIN determinations b ON a.CollectionID = b.CollectionID 
LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(a, *, '"*fa*"') ct1 on a.CollectionID = ct1.[Key]
LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(b, *, '"*fa*"') ct2 on b.CollectionID = ct2.[Key]
WHERE      a.CollrTeam_Text LIKE '%fa%'
           OR ct1.[Key] IS NOT NULL
           OR ct2.[Key] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Incredible, even better performance. Again DISTINCT had to be added and CONTAINSTABLE needed the actual table names, but with some minor tweaks it ran perfect.  Cost comparison between the 3 methods: 29%, 32%, and 38% (CONTAINSTABLE, LEFT OUTER JOIN, then UNION).  Logical reads now 1/5 of the UNION query.  Well done.

Comment: if you just need the `CollectionID` then you don't even need to do the joins. You can use `ct1.Key as CollectionID`

Answer (score 3):

I was going to suggest to `UNION` each as their own query, but as I read your question I saw that you have found that.  I can't think of a better way, so if it helps use it.  The `UNION` method is a common approach to a poor performing query that has several OR conditions where each performs well on its own.

Comment: +1 I would also suggest UNION. As a note, I would say that UNION is the *right* solution, not the workaround.

Comment: Thanks, the reassurance that the UNION approach is very helpful; plus it doesn't hurt that the query runs well now to boot.

Comment: And if the two union statements will be mutually exclusive every time, then use UNION ALL for additional performance imporvements.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use the UNION. If you are really against it, you might try something like:

```
SELECT a.CollectionID
FROM collections a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CollectionID FROM collections WHERE CONTAINS(*, '"*fa*"')) c
    ON c.CollectionID = a.CollectionID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CollectionID FROM determinations WHERE CONTAINS(*, '"*fa*"')) d
    ON d.CollectionID = a.CollectionID
WHERE a.CollrTeam_Text LIKE '%fa%'
   OR c.CollectionID IS NOT NULL
   OR d.CollectionID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I had to add DISTINCT, but this actually results in a slight performance improvement over the UNION method. Cost comparison is 46% to 54% with about 2/3rd the number of logical reads.  Intriguing!

Answer (score 0):

We've experience the exact same problem and at the time, put it down to our query being badly formed - that SQL 2005 had let us get away with it, but 2008 wouldn't.

In the end, we split the query into 2 SELECTs that were called using an IF. Glad someone else has had the same problem and that it's a known issue. We were seeing queries on a table with ~150,000 rows + full-text going from < 1 second (2005) to 30+ seconds (2008).

Comment: Exactly!  This query was originally working fine on a SQL 2000 machine, but once we moved to SQL 2008 this appeared.  Welcome to our new club.